# Do the Range TS and C++20 concepts for iterators require the ability to use `operator->`?

Tags: c++, c++20

I've searched through various Range TS proposals, including P0896, the one incorporating the ranges into C++20. It seems from my reading that the only requirement the `Iterator` concept makes in terms of dereferenceability is that `*t` be valid syntax that yields an object of some type.

Since `InputIterator` is defined in terms of being an `Iterator` and being `Readable`, neither of which requires `operator->` support, it appears that the Range TS and C++20 do not require that iterators provide `->` support.

Is this the case?

Comment: Hm. It's still listed in the input iterator requirements in [P1037](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1037r0.pdf) (search for `a->m`). But there's a sentence striking out that requirement elsewhere (search for `i->m`).

Comment: Of course `Iterator<int*>` and `InputIterator<int*>` should be true. Not that the proposal couldn't require an `operator->` when the value type is a class type only, but I'm not sure if that wouldn't introduce other complications.

Comment: @Barry In P1037R0, it looks to me like the arrow requirement applies to the English term "input iterator" but not the C++ concept `std::ranges::Iterator`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, we've dropped the `operator->` requirement from `InputIterator`, and consequently the iterator concepts that refine it. (The requirement remains part of the "old" input iterator requirements, which are unchanged.) There are a number of reasons:

1. There's no way to implement `->` for many iterator types such that the semantics of `i->m` are equivalent to `(*i).m` [as the "old" requirements expect](http://eel.is/c++draft/input.iterators#2.sentence-22). `move_iterator` is a good example: `(*i).m` is an rvalue, whereas `i->m` is an lvalue. (Yes, it's yet another Standard iterator that doesn't satisfy the iterator requirements.)
2. There's no way to usefully constrain `->` with concepts. Sure, we could require that there *is* an `operator->`, but we couldn't constrain it to have reasonable syntax.
3. Most importantly, `->` is useless to the standard algorithms: they have no idea if the elements denoted by an iterator have members, let alone how to name such members.

This doesn't mean that standard iterators won't provide `operator->` (Although see [LWG 2790](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2790)), only that iterators aren't required to implement such an operator to be usable with the standard library.

Comment: The last paragraph describes a good design practice: provide as much functionality as possible, but require as little as needed. Generosity of design, of sorts :)