Why is the arrow operator not generated?
I'm trying to write an iterator Iter such that std::iterator_traits<Iter> deduces a maximum amount of information from it. To this end, if I understood correctly, Iter needs to "satisfy the exposition-only concept __LegacyInputIterator" (cppreference) and that concept needs Iter to implement operator->() (cppreference).
It seems to me that, in 99% of all cases, the behavior of operator->() is (conceptually) the same as operator*()'s behavior and, thus, could almost certainly be generated by the compiler for me, but a quick test on godbolt indicates that it isn't.
Is there a good reason for this? Am I missing anything?
EDIT: here's the godbolt-code:
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

pair<int, int> p{0,0};

template<class T>
concept has_arrow = requires(T t){
    *t;
    t->first;
};

struct MyIter {
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = pair<int, int>;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type*;

    reference operator*() { return p; }
    // uncommenting the following fixes the compile-error
    //pointer operator->() { return &p; } 
};

int main() {
    // error: "base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'MyIter'"
    static_assert(has_arrow<MyIter>); 
}


Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51093479/do-the-range-ts-and-c20-concepts-for-iterators-require-the-ability-to-use-ope

You should also post your godbolt's code example here on SO. A link is not enough.

they are never "the same"

@463035818_is_not_an_ai true, but operator!= is not "the same" as operator== still the compiler can figure it out...

I'd guess that unlike the comparison operators the * and -> operators aren't overloaded sufficiently regularly or with sufficiently fixed patterns for anybody to propose auto generating them to the standard committee

The answer is always the same: it wasn't proposed yet, or the proposal wasn't accepted. != being generated automatically is a new feature, it's not surprising they didn't try to add other operators all at once.

Should it return address-of reference, invoke operator-> on reference, or?

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I'd propose returning the address of whatever is returned by operator*, as long as that's a (const) reference; otherwise, do not generate operator->. Will this produce dangling pointers if operator* returns a lifetime extended const-ref?

@igel I might be be tempted to invert this.  Have operator* return * on the return value of operator->; this works for clever pointers in better ways I think.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont seems reasonable. I have written iterator-like classes in the past whose operator* returns an lvalue and the operator-> would return a wrapper where operator* just returns a ref to the object itself -- in these cases, generating operator* from operator-> would be the way better choice; plus, it wouldn't break classes where operator-> was intentionally left out, which seems more likely than writing operator-> and leaving out operator* intentionally ^^
